# How can I find the hypotenuse and opposite sides of triangle?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Based on the given information how can I find the pixel values of the hypotenuse and opposite sides of the triangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a right triangle with angle measuring $81^{\circ}$, an opposite side $O = 1200 px$. The angle measuring $81^{\circ}$ is adjacent to $A = x$, unknown, and a hypotenuse of $H = y$, unknown.

Applying trigonometric identities:

$\sin(81^{\circ}) = \frac OH = \frac {1200}{y}$

$\cos(81^{\circ}) = \frac AH = \frac  xy$

$\tan(81^{\circ}) = \frac OA = \frac {1200}y$.

So...